# Create Python object from table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the results of a SQL query,in table form, as below:

```
State       County      City
California  Monterey    Salinas
California  Monterey    Gonzalez
California  Alameda     Oakland
California  Alameda     Berkeley
Oregon      Douglas     Roseberg
Oregon      Douglas     Winston
Oregon      Jackson     Medford
Oregon      Jackson     Jacksonville
```

I want to create a python object that does not have duplicates in the states, and rolls up the cities, as below:

```
    stateObject = {
        "California": {
            "Monterey": ["Salinas", "Gonzales"],
            "Alameda": ["Oakland", "Berkeley"]
        },
        "Oregon": {
            "Douglas": ["Roseburg", "Winston"],
            "Jackson": ["Medford", "Jacksonville"]
        }
    }
```

How do I go about creating this object?

Comment: do you have any code at all?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You should read about [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want to have a positive response. A good rule is to always include the code you tried so far, or at least relevant parts of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = """State       County      City
California  Monterey    Salinas
California  Monterey    Gonzalez
California  Alameda     Oakland
California  Alameda     Berkeley
Oregon      Douglas     Roseberg
Oregon      Douglas     Winston
Oregon      Jackson     Medford
Oregon      Jackson     Jacksonville"""

stateObject = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for line in s.split("\n")[1:]:
    state, county, city = line.split()
    stateObject[state][county].append(city)
```